# Anylogic - Changing a Variable \ Parameter in a resource

Tags: anylogic

I'm building a model, where each resource has a value that changed after supplying a service to an agent. How can I change the value of the Variable \ Parameter that I placed in the resource?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

1) Add a resource type to your model
[image: Resource Type]

2) The resource type (let's call it Resource) has to include a variable (let's call this variable var of type double with initial value 0). You can add this parameter when you create the resource type.

3) Go to your resource Pool. The new resource has to be of type Resource:
[image: resource type]

4) In your resourcePool in the "on release" action, you can add your code to change the value of the variable:
[image: change variable]

Comment: Thank you. If I want to change the value of the variable when an agents goes through a delay block (while he is assigned a resource)?

Comment: Also, how can I change it to a specific value? When I write unit.var=4.5 it gives me an error: "cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: if it gives you an error, it means that var is not defined as a variable in your resource agent

Comment: and if you want to change it in a delay block, it's a totally different answer... Your question is not very good in that case... Since you said you had a service

Comment: Thanks again :). What do I need to do to make sure the var is defined as variable?

Also can you also elaborate on how to do it in a delay block?

Your answers are a life saver.

Comment: to do it in a delay block you have to define the resource in the agent and in the delay you would have to do agent.resource.var=something; And you make sure var is defined as a variable by going to your resource agent and verify that the variable exists there